# How to "terminate" inside of init

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class that does some sanity checks inside `__init__`. If some of these fail, I want to stop processing `__init__`.

Example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, hostname, conn=None, user=None, passwd=None):
        # SNIP (code to check if connection was supplied, if not user/pass)
        if not conn.is_logged_in():
            if not conn.Login():
                raise LoginFailed("Failed to login to '%s'" % hostname)
                return
        # some code that relies on valid connection
```

If I want to cease processing after this first sanity check, how can this be done? The actual code I'm writing establishes a connection to a REST service, so my first sanity check is to test the provided connection, or, if provided a username and password instead, establish the connection in `__init__()`.

Obviously if the connection fails, I don't want to execute the subsequent tasks that rely on the connection. Essentially I want the object creation to fail.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with raising an exception?

Comment: Do you mean something specific by "terminate"? You're already raising an exception if you can't log in; what other behavior are you looking for besides this?

Comment: I'm with @dm03514. Seems like this is exactly what exceptions are for.

Comment: The code you posted will do just that: it will stop execution at the `raise` statement (or more exactly, pass execution to the first exception handler for 'LoginFailed' or one of it's superclasses, which by default is the top-level interpreter exception handler).

Comment: Well I'm raising an exception that I'm checking in my client code. My point is I want execution of init to stop after I raise that exception. I tried return but it doesnt seem to work. This class is actually part of a library and called from client code. As it is now, it continues on and I get all the errors that code later in init generates.

Comment: "My point is I want execution of init to stop after I raise that exception." It already does. That's exactly what throwing an exception already accomplishes. When you raise that LoginFailed exception, execution of `__init__` ends. Whatever problem it is you're having, it's not due to `__init__` continuing to execute. There's something else going wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @BenH what would make you think that when you raise an exception, processing would continue? have you tried printing something out to test and see how that works?

Comment: Ok let me look at my code and see what else could be wrong. As it is now, in my client code I still get the logging (which are errors) for tasks that happen after I do this sanity check and raise an exception.

Comment: You say "it continues on"... but does the exception *actually get raised*? My bet is no, it doesn't. Either `conn.is_logged_in()` is truthy or `conn.Login()` is truthy. (Or conceivably there is a problem in your snipped section(s), depending on how much you've altered your actual code before posting it here.)

Comment: Keep in mind that a lot of folks use the convention that 0 (falsy) is returned for **successful** completion, and nonzero (truthy) for an error condition. This is especially true if the code you're calling is a thin wrapper over C code. (Point being that `conn.Login()` might return 0 for *successful login*, for example.)

Comment: Technically, object *creation* has already succeeded by the time `__init__` is called. (`__init__` initializes a newly created object, hence the name.)

Answer (score 1):

On C++ we use `while break`.
In python that would be:

```
def __init__(self):
    while True:
        # Note that all the relevant code goes here. Inside the while
        if not conn.is_logged_in():
            if not conn.Login():
                # raise LoginFailed("Failed to login to '%s'" % hostname)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sys.exit()`, although this does what your code already does.

You could also `return` from the `init` method to stop processing, and this won't raise a fatal error, but will stop the method.

Comment: I tried return but it doesn't work. If my first sanity check fails, it continues on and I get all the logging and errors further down in init.

Comment: @BenH Can you post the code with return in the question?

Comment: Ok, updated the code to show how I tried using return.

Comment: @BenH Remove the `raise` line.